# How to switching the stack's widget of index

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

How to switching the stack's widget smoothly when clicking the smaller widget, mentioned as the image below

[image: When user has clicked Widget B, widget b will zoom out, and widget a will be zoom in, and the stack position will be changed when clicked smaller widget]

When user has clicked Widget B, Widget B will zoom out, and Widget A will zoom in, and the stack position should be changed when clicked the smaller widget.

Any code sample for reference would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Widget _a = Container(
      color: Colors.red, width: double.infinity, height: double.infinity);
  Widget _b = Container(
      color: Colors.green, width: double.infinity, height: double.infinity);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: 400,
        height: 200,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 400,
              height: 200,
              child: _a,
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 20,
              left: 20,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  Widget _swap = _b;
                  _b = _a;
                  _a = _swap;
                  setState((){});
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 80,
                  height: 40,
                  child: _b,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```